# Передача параметров функции

Tags: x86-64, c, gcc, linux

В архитектуре x86_64 параметры согласно ABI передаются функции не через стек, как это по умолчанию в х86, а через регистры RDI, RSI и т.д. В x86 есть параметр gcc, который включает такую "регистровую" передачу (-mregparm). Вопрос: имеется ли подобный параметр для  gcc x64, который бы включал передачу параметров через стек, как в x86?

Comment: Интересно, а если загнать параметр (int) в структуру и передать ее ? Думаю положит в стек. Это если надо передать параметр именно в стеке.
Конечно ***нормальная*** функция его не примет.

Comment: Согласно ABI х64 структуры передаются через стек. А вообще, можно на досуге попробовать...

Comment: Почему не примет? Если параметром будет структура, примет и никуда не денется.

Comment: Ну это понятно. 

Я имел в виду функцию (допустим на ассемблере), которая ожидает целый аргумент именно в стеке (что запрещено согласно...). Ну, так ее написали, а теперь интересно, как ее вызвать из Си.

Comment: Можно попробовать так поизвращаться: перед вызовом этой функции объявить локальную переменную с параметром volatile, инициировать ее и далее вызвать функцию. ТЕОРЕТИЧЕСКИ эта переменная должна попасть в стек как раз перед прелюдией. А функцию объявить и вызвать без соответствующего параметра ))) 

Ну или Ваш вариант со структурой тоже неплох. Правда, тут непонятно что будет с оптимизацией...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сделать то, что запрещено согласно [**AMD64 calling convention**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI_convention), которая определяет, что 6 первых `integer-like` параметров должны передаваться через регистры. *Это сделано частично из соображений производительности, частично - из соображений безопасности, т.к в случае такой конвенции вызовов атаки на стек для большинства функций становятся чрезвычайно затруднительными.*

Чисто теоретически, готов предположить, что саму по себе конвенцию возможно было бы обойти, однако, лично я не представляю себе, **как сделать это без нарушения `ABI` совместимости.**

Comment: Т.е., никак и никогда? ABI для х32 предполагает передачу через стек, но есть возможность заставать gcc передавать через регистры, т.е. тоже нарушить ABI. Для х64 такой возможности, получается, совершенно не предоставляется.

Comment: @mikillskegg Если разговор идет об `AMD64`, то здесь выбора не остается, т.к передача через регистры **навязана** самой конвенцией. Подозреваю, что в случае `Microsoft x64 calling convention` ситуация обстоит схожим образом, разве что там через регистры передаются 4, а не 6 переменных. *Следуя из этих соображений, под `x64` опция `-mregparm` просто невозможна, и разработчики, очевидно, не позволяют ее использовать.*

Comment: @milkillskegg Если не секрет, как вообще возник этот вопрос?)

Comment: Из любопытства )))

В ходе углубленного изучения NASM для х64

Comment: @mikillskegg Неслабое, конечно, у вас любопытство)

Comment: А то... )))